# DB2 fetch failure error

Tags: db2, fetch

Am using DB2 database connection with PHP. When I run the particular query, it throws the below error

```
Error : db2_fetch_assoc(): Fetch Failure in...
```

The query will be like this.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(concat('2011-07-18 ', hour)) AS orderTime from schedules
```

The query executes well. But When I try to fetch the records, it throws error. The hour value will be like '08:30:00'

Comment: You need to provide also the contents of your three subquery variables (`$reminderSQL`, etc)

Comment: Its bcos of the this query   select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(concat(VARCHAR_FORMAT(current_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),concat(' ','03:30:00'))) from sysibm.sysdummy1

Comment: You can edit your question to make it more clear...

Answer (score 0):

You Should run the same query on DB2 control center or db2cmd first, Then error can be more clear.

Moreover you can share rows of schedules table to understand the exact problem.