# db2_fetch_object(): Fetch Failure thrown when query works in strsql

Tags: php, db2, db2-400

I'm getting the following error when running a query in PHP:

> Warning:  db2_fetch_object(): Fetch Failure in ... on line 15

The strange thing is that when I run the same query in my I5 terminal using `strsql` it works, and I get a nice recordset. The query I ran is `SELECT * FROM TABLE(U8.feedconst(0)) AS t1`.

`U8.feedconst(0)` is a table function that resides in the U8 library, but pulls data from the user's library. When I use the IBM terminal, I set the user's library with `uasetlibl`. The library is specified in the PHP DB2 connection in $this->user->library (that library is used successfully in other queries).

Here is the PHP code:

```
$this->conn = db2_connect(
        \HOST, 
        $this->user->username, 
        $this->user->password,
        array('i5_libl' => $this->user->library . ' ' . \PROD_LIB,
            'i5_naming' => DB2_I5_NAMING_ON)
);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE(U8.feedconst(0)) AS t1';
$stmt = db2_prepare($this->conn, $sql);
if ($stmt) {
    $this->user->log('stmt = ' . strval($stmt), true);
    $exec = db2_execute($stmt);
    if ($exec) {
        $this->user->log('exec = ' . strval($exec), true);
        $this->user->log('db2_stmt_errormsg = ' . db2_stmt_errormsg($stmt), true);
        while ($row = db2_fetch_object($stmt)) {
            $this->user->log($sql, true);
        }
    }
}
```

The log shows that everything is looking good until the `db2_fetch_object()` line:

```
2015-11-18 10:43:53pm : stmt = Resource id #21
2015-11-18 10:43:53pm : exec = 1
2015-11-18 10:54:27pm : db2_stmt_errormsg =
```

As you can see, I tried to get the real error from DB2 using `db2_stmt_errormsg()`, but it's not returning anything.

I looked at other similar questions, like [Warning: db2_fetch_assoc(): Fetch Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483943/warning-db2-fetch-assoc-fetch-failure) and [DB2 fetch failure error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729663/db2-fetch-failure-error) but they don't seem to address my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of my grief. It seems that there was an additional library that was used internally by the table function. Since that table function had a dependency in a different library, and that other library was not included in my library list, the recordset returned to PHP was empty.

It worked in the i5 terminal because my terminal session was already setup to include that other library in its library list, unbeknownst to me.

When I added the other internal library to my library list in the connection, the query worked in PHP just fine.

If anyone else runs into this, make sure you are including all libraries used by your query, including any that may be internal dependencies.